# Can you add a custom item to Minecraft Java using a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm trying to add a custom item to Minecraft that players can use as a currency (e.g., a gold coin block). Can I do this with a resource pack, or do I need a full client-side mod? I haven't been able to find anything about it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, adding custom items using resource packs isn't possible.

Resource packs only provide a way to modify certain aspects of in-game elements, according to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack):

> The resource pack system provides a way for players to customize textures, models, music, sounds, languages, texts such as the end poem, splashes, credits, and fonts

However, maybe what you're looking for is a [data pack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack). Data packs cannot add completely new items, but can be used to add modified versions of items that, when combined with resource packs, look like a completely new item.

I found this tutorial on YouTube showing how to add "custom items" through data packs, maybe you'll find it useful: